# Zebra printer isn't printing all the ZPL labels

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am trying to send a bulk of ZPL commands to print the labels but the printer accepts only 4/5 labels randomly and prints them. I am not sure whether it is a printer limit to accept certain numbers of labels or if it is my side issue I am not creating ZPL code correctly.

We are using [ZT410 Printer](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printers/industrial/zt410.html). I have also tried the [ZPL Emulator Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zpl-printer/phoidlklenidapnijkabnfdgmadlcmjo) and it shows the same issue.

Please advise, Here is the ZPL code.

```
^XA ^LH10,10
^FO200,30^CFA, 36^FDLabel 0^FS
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,0^CFA, 36^FD420mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,56^CFA, 36^FD1000mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,112^CFA, 36^FD1/1 1/1000mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,168^CFA, 36^FD3 ^FS 
^FO0,244^BQN,2,3,Q,7^FDQ,Name "One", Sheetlength 420, Ends 0/0, 0/0:Offset 140, Angle -95, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 250, Angle -100, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 320, Angle 115, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0; ReverseColours, Customer "Sean Test", Materialname "Colorbond", Colour "Paperbark", JobLength 1000, JobQuantity 1, JobWidth 420, Width 420, DateEntered "Thu, 01 Jun 2023 02:55:45", DeliveryDate "2023-06-03", Rotation 0
 ^FS
^XZ


^XA ^LH10,10
^FO200,30^CFA, 36^FDLabel 1^FS
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,0^CFA, 36^FD420mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,56^CFA, 36^FD1002mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,112^CFA, 36^FD1/1 1/1002mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,168^CFA, 36^FD3 ^FS 
^FO0,244^BQN,2,3,Q,7^FDQ,Name "Two", Sheetlength 420, Ends 0/0, 0/0:Offset 140, Angle -95, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 250, Angle -100, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 320, Angle 115, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0; ReverseColours, Customer "Sean Test", Materialname "Colorbond", Colour "Paperbark", JobLength 1002, JobQuantity 1, JobWidth 420, Width 420, DateEntered "Thu, 01 Jun 2023 02:55:45", DeliveryDate "2023-06-03", Rotation 0
 ^FS
^XZ


^XA ^LH10,10
^FO200,30^CFA, 36^FDLabel 2^FS
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,0^CFA, 36^FD420mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,56^CFA, 36^FD1003mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,112^CFA, 36^FD1/1 1/1003mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,168^CFA, 36^FD3 ^FS 
^FO0,244^BQN,2,3,Q,7^FDQ,Name "Three", Sheetlength 420, Ends 0/0, 0/0:Offset 140, Angle -95, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 250, Angle -100, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 320, Angle 115, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0; ReverseColours, Customer "Sean Test", Materialname "Colorbond", Colour "Paperbark", JobLength 1003, JobQuantity 1, JobWidth 420, Width 420, DateEntered "Thu, 01 Jun 2023 02:55:45", DeliveryDate "2023-06-03", Rotation 0
 ^FS
^XZ


^XA ^LH10,10
^FO200,30^CFA, 36^FDLabel 3^FS
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,0^CFA, 36^FD420mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,56^CFA, 36^FD1004mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,112^CFA, 36^FD1/1 1/1004mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,168^CFA, 36^FD3 ^FS 
^FO0,244^BQN,2,3,Q,7^FDQ,Name "Four", Sheetlength 420, Ends 0/0, 0/0:Offset 140, Angle -95, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 250, Angle -100, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 320, Angle 115, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0; ReverseColours, Customer "Sean Test", Materialname "Colorbond", Colour "Paperbark", JobLength 1004, JobQuantity 1, JobWidth 420, Width 420, DateEntered "Thu, 01 Jun 2023 02:55:45", DeliveryDate "2023-06-03", Rotation 0
 ^FS
^XZ


^XA ^LH10,10
^FO200,30^CFA, 36^FDLabel 4^FS
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,0^CFA, 36^FD420mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,56^CFA, 36^FD1005mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,112^CFA, 36^FD1/1 1/1005mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,168^CFA, 36^FD3 ^FS 
^FO0,244^BQN,2,3,Q,7^FDQ,Name "Five", Sheetlength 420, Ends 0/0, 0/0:Offset 140, Angle -95, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 250, Angle -100, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 320, Angle 115, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0; ReverseColours, Customer "Sean Test", Materialname "Colorbond", Colour "Paperbark", JobLength 1005, JobQuantity 1, JobWidth 420, Width 420, DateEntered "Thu, 01 Jun 2023 02:55:45", DeliveryDate "2023-06-03", Rotation 0
 ^FS
^XZ


^XA ^LH10,10
^FO200,30^CFA, 36^FDLabel 5^FS
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,0^CFA, 36^FD420mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,56^CFA, 36^FD1006mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,112^CFA, 36^FD1/1 1/1006mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,168^CFA, 36^FD3 ^FS 
^FO0,244^BQN,2,3,Q,7^FDQ,Name "Six", Sheetlength 420, Ends 0/0, 0/0:Offset 140, Angle -95, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 250, Angle -100, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 320, Angle 115, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0; ReverseColours, Customer "Sean Test", Materialname "Colorbond", Colour "Paperbark", JobLength 1006, JobQuantity 1, JobWidth 420, Width 420, DateEntered "Thu, 01 Jun 2023 02:55:45", DeliveryDate "2023-06-03", Rotation 0
 ^FS
^XZ


^XA ^LH10,10
^FO200,30^CFA, 36^FDLabel 6^FS
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,0^CFA, 36^FD420mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,56^CFA, 36^FD1007mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,112^CFA, 36^FD1/1 1/1007mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,168^CFA, 36^FD3 ^FS 
^FO0,244^BQN,2,3,Q,7^FDQ,Name "Seven", Sheetlength 420, Ends 0/0, 0/0:Offset 140, Angle -95, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 250, Angle -100, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 320, Angle 115, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0; ReverseColours, Customer "Sean Test", Materialname "Colorbond", Colour "Paperbark", JobLength 1007, JobQuantity 1, JobWidth 420, Width 420, DateEntered "Thu, 01 Jun 2023 02:55:45", DeliveryDate "2023-06-03", Rotation 0
 ^FS
^XZ


^XA ^LH10,10
^FO200,30^CFA, 36^FDLabel 7^FS
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,0^CFA, 36^FD170mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,56^CFA, 36^FD1005mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,112^CFA, 36^FD1/3 3/1005mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,168^CFA, 36^FD2 ^FS 
^FO0,244^BQN,2,3,Q,7^FDQ,Name "TT3", Sheetlength 170, Ends 0/0, 0/0:Offset 80, Angle -90, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 160, Angle 65, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0; ReverseColours, Customer "Sean Test", Materialname "Colorbond-Matt", Colour "Surfmist Matt", JobLength 1005, JobQuantity 3, JobWidth 170, Width 170, DateEntered "Thu, 01 Jun 2023 02:55:45", DeliveryDate "2023-06-03", Rotation 0
 ^FS
^XZ


^XA ^LH10,10
^FO200,30^CFA, 36^FDLabel 8^FS
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,0^CFA, 36^FD170mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,56^CFA, 36^FD1005mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,112^CFA, 36^FD2/3 3/1005mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,168^CFA, 36^FD2 ^FS 
^FO0,244^BQN,2,3,Q,7^FDQ,Name "TT3", Sheetlength 170, Ends 0/0, 0/0:Offset 80, Angle -90, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 160, Angle 65, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0; ReverseColours, Customer "Sean Test", Materialname "Colorbond-Matt", Colour "Surfmist Matt", JobLength 1005, JobQuantity 3, JobWidth 170, Width 170, DateEntered "Thu, 01 Jun 2023 02:55:45", DeliveryDate "2023-06-03", Rotation 0
 ^FS
^XZ


^XA ^LH10,10
^FO200,30^CFA, 36^FDLabel 9^FS
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,0^CFA, 36^FD170mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,56^CFA, 36^FD1005mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,112^CFA, 36^FD3/3 3/1005mm ^FS 
^FB1300,2,20,L,0^FO0,168^CFA, 36^FD2 ^FS 
^FO0,244^BQN,2,3,Q,7^FDQ,Name "TT3", Sheetlength 170, Ends 0/0, 0/0:Offset 80, Angle -90, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0;Offset 160, Angle 65, Type 0, Radius 0, ClampHt 0; ReverseColours, Customer "Sean Test", Materialname "Colorbond-Matt", Colour "Surfmist Matt", JobLength 1005, JobQuantity 3, JobWidth 170, Width 170, DateEntered "Thu, 01 Jun 2023 02:55:45", DeliveryDate "2023-06-03", Rotation 0
 ^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: have you tried to add a ^PQ1 command to each of the labels?

Comment: I have sent complex print jobs with a hundred or more unique labels, in one stream of ZPL, to a printer. I had no problems with a limit. I tried rendering your labels directly on printer and no problems. Might have to try WireShark and inspect all the TCP/IP traffic going to the printer. That's quite a dense QR code; I predict you will see issues with that QR code as time passes.

Comment: @ZRep Yes, I tried the ^PQ1 command, but it doesn't make any impact.

Comment: @EdHayes3 I have tried without QR code and it prints only 6 labels.

Comment: So just send the labels one by one!?